# missing pdflatex primitives for lualatex

Tags: luatex

I am trying to switch from pdflatex to lualatex.  alas, some primitives (such as `\pdfmatch`) have disappeared.

```
\newcommand{\instring}[4]{%
  % \instring{<pattern>}{<heystring>}{<true>}{<false>}
  \ifnum\pdfmatch{#1}{#2}=1
    #3%
  \else
    #4%
  \fi
}
```

is there a plugin style file that brings back pdfmatch when running under lualatex?

Comment: I don't think that there is something like this. Most other pdfTeX names can be restored with the `luatex85` package. But `\pdfmatch` is complicated. There are multiple great pattern matching systems in Lua which would be almost trivial to build a similar interface  with, but neither one of those are fully compatible with extended POSIX regular expressions. So implementing `\pdfmatch` would require linking a C library (requiring shell-escape and almost certainly not being distributed in common distributions) or implementing a POSIX regex parser in Lua.

Comment: If you don't need full compatibility, it gets rather easy to get equivalent functionality though. But we would have to see some typical patterns you need to implement something along that path.

Comment: Hans removed a number of primitives in LuaTeX because the _concepts_ were covered better from Lua. As Marcel says, you can put back some _names_ (some as the primitives are renamed, some as they can be emulated in Lua), but really that's a sticking plaster to allow a few edge cases to work - you are better updating your sources. On `\pdfmatch`, it was never well-documented and Lua patterns or LPEG are the way to go. I'm not sure if that is really an answer here - it depends very much on your use case.

Comment: thanks, everyone.  I am just started on lualatex, so I am afraid I will have to post a few more starter questions soon.

Comment: actually, can I beg someone to post the canonical implementation where #1 is just a string?  I am afraid if I put something up, as a beginner, I would butcher it with something that works but is ugly and should not be copied.  and, if posted, then mention that the full implementation is not worth it?  I can then accept the answer as the solution.

Comment: @joseph-wright do you know if the removed primitives and the justification of their removal are documented somewhere?